# Why is $Z_p[x]$ left and right distributive

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modular-arithmetic

I did not get to the section on field theory in the book I am studying from, so I’m not looking for someone to generalize straight over my question with any results on fields that may make this an obvious exercise.

Let $Z_p[x]$ denote all polynomials of indeterminate $x$ with coefficients element of $Z_p$, i.e. the integers modulo $p$. Let the operations of addition ($+$) and multiplication (juxtaposition of elements) by doing ordinary polynomial addition and multiplication but reducing the coefficients modulo $p$.
I am trying to show that this multiplication in $Z_p[x]$ is left and right distributive over addition. I am totally aware I should be using the following:

1. $(a+b)\bmod n = (a\bmod n)+(b\bmod n) \bmod n$
2. $ab\bmod n = (a\bmod n)(b\bmod n)\bmod n$
3. The above results and the commutativity of $Z_n$ imply that integers modulo $n$ are left and right distributive.

However I’m not sure at all how the above results imply left and right distributivity of $Z_p[x].$ I tried doing induction on the degrees of the polynomials involved in the expression $f(g+h)$ but I’m not sure if there’s easier methods.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: "I am trying to show that $Z_p[x]$ is a field whenever $p$ is prime." This isn't true. In fact, $R[x]$ is never a field no matter what $R$ is.

Comment: Whoops, thank you. I forgot to change that.

Comment: I think you should just write $f=\sum_i a_i x^i$, $g=$, $h=$ and then $f(g+h)=\sum_n \sum_{i+j=n} a_i (b_j+c_j) x^n$ and $fg+fh=\sum_n \sum_{i+j=n} (a_i b_j+a_i  c_j) x^n$ and all is clear.

Comment: Don’t use $x$ as a variable when you also use is at an indeterminate in a polynomial ring. Apt to be confusing.

Comment: How do you define $\mathbb Z_p[x]?$ Technically, the distributive law is easy to prove, but it is tedious and heavily depends on the definition.

Comment: Do you know multiplication is commutative? Because then you only have to prove one sided distributive law. The outline of the proof is to prove $x(f(x)+g(x))=xf(x)+xg(x)$ and $a(f(x)+g(x))$ for $a\in \mathbb Z_p$ and then prove $h(x)(f(x)+g(x))=h(x)f(x)+h(x)g(x)$ for a general polynomial via induction on the degree of $h.$

Comment: In four places you use the phrase "... the ring is distributive" or "the distributivity of [the ring]". Everyone thus far has assumed you are talking about the distributivity of multiplication over addition, but are you actually talking about the ring property wherein the lattice of ideals is distributive?

Comment: If you are talking about the operation then you could not "use the ring axioms" because you would be establishing one of those axioms. The distributive axiom does not follow from the other axioms even if you do believe the first two you listed.  And you wouldn't really talk about a "ring being distributive" but rather its "multiplication being distributive over its addition."

Comment: @rschwieb Thank you. You are right, I should change the wording in my question in that regard. I am not sure what you mean by “wherein the lattice of ideals is distributive” because I didn’t learn what an ideal is yet - so what I was speaking about was distributivity of multiplication over addition. I will change what I meant by ring axioms - sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @Thomas Andrews Thank you. I was trying something pretty similar and that helps a lot. I will change the unknowns I use in my three points.

Comment: @ancient mathematician Thank you for the simple proof. I tried thinking to myself that it’d be best to keep track of what one coefficient does in the multiplication process but then I proceeded with another inductive argument.

Comment: @Thomas Andrews I’ll define $Z_p[x]$ in the post now.

Comment: Are you familiar with rings? What is you definition / construction of a polynomial ring $R[x]$?

Comment: Also, what is your definition of $\,\Bbb Z_p?\,$  Do you know it is a (quotient) ring, or are you working only with congruences?